Trying to make a heatmap based on percentage values from zip code area
I've been trying to use the choroplethrZip package to do this based on a previous post, but my version of R will not support this package. I'm using the data set and code below, and believe I have it formatted correctly.



region
value




19102
0.33


19103
0.0625


19106
0.25


19107
0.119


19111
0


19114
0


19115
0.476


19116
0.0909


19120
0.0556


19121
0.107


19122
0.158


19124
0.1


19125
0.133


19128
0.05


19129
0


19130
0.048


19131
0


19132
0.158


19133
0.0667


19134
0.108


19135
0.2


19136
0.08


19137
0


19138
0.037


19139
0


19140
0.048


19141
0


19142
0.0909


19143
0.027


19144
0.174


19145
0.108


19146
0.079


19147
0.048


19148
0.156


19149
0


19150
0.045


19152
0


19154
0



library(choroplethrZip)

coag20 <- read_excel("comorbheatmap.xlsx", sheet = 1)

zip_choropleth(coag20, zip_zoom = (coag20$region),
               num_colors = 1, 
               title = "Comorbidity Documentation per Encounter by Zip Code: Coagulopathy",
               legend = "Percentage")


What error message(s) are you getting when you run this code? How does your actual output differ from your expected output?

The package is not on CRAN, but is available from github. How did you try to install it? Something like remotes::install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')?

For a more future-proof option, you can use tigris for the zipcode geometries, and ggplot2 for plotting:
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Your example data
coag20 <- read.table(text = "region     value
19102   0.33
19103   0.0625
19106   0.25
19107   0.119
19111   0
19114   0
19115   0.476
19116   0.0909
19120   0.0556
19121   0.107
19122   0.158
19124   0.1
19125   0.133
19128   0.05
19129   0
19130   0.048
19131   0
19132   0.158
19133   0.0667
19134   0.108
19135   0.2
19136   0.08
19137   0
19138   0.037
19139   0
19140   0.048
19141   0
19142   0.0909
19143   0.027
19144   0.174
19145   0.108
19146   0.079
19147   0.048
19148   0.156
19149   0
19150   0.045
19152   0
19154   0", header = TRUE)

# Load sf of all zipcodes starting with the same two digits of your area of interest
sf_zip <- zctas(starts_with = "19", class = "sf")

# Subset sf_zip to just the zipcodes in coag20, join values to sf
sf_coag20 <- filter(sf_zip, ZCTA5CE20 %in% coag20$region) |>
  mutate(ZCTA5CE20 = as.integer(ZCTA5CE20)) |>
  left_join(coag20, by = join_by(ZCTA5CE20 == region))

sf_coag20[,c(1,10)]
# Simple feature collection with 38 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -75.26443 ymin: 39.89184 xmax: -74.95576 ymax: 40.13799
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
# First 10 features:
#    ZCTA5CE20  value                       geometry
# 1      19143 0.0270 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.25165 3...
# 2      19137 0.0000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.09842 3...
# 3      19129 0.0000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.20801 4...
# 4      19115 0.4760 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.07456 4...
# 5      19103 0.0625 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.18325 3...
# 6      19142 0.0909 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.24776 3...
# 7      19131 0.0000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.24977 3...
# 8      19107 0.1190 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.1653 39...
# 9      19124 0.1000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.12714 4...
# 10     19133 0.0667 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.1549 39...

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_coag20, aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Percentage") +
  labs(title = "Comorbidity Documentation per Encounter by Zip Code: Coagulopathy") +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 8))


